# Undo, Redo in Sudoku game Android

Tags: java, android, game-engine

I'm trying to implement a undo and redo button in my android sudoku game, but it's complicated cause the user can draft(put in numbers they think could potentially be the answer to a cell), insert value they think it is, remove specific number from draft or value and delete all the draft values. I was thinking of using a stack that holds some sort of object that saves the state of another object and just pop then revert it back, but I can't seem to find anything that does that. The momento object seems to be the closest, but I think that only saves 1 state and returns that state. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell{
isNotEditable
DraftValue
Value
X
Y
}

SudokuStep{
ArrayList<Cell>
}
```

You can keep all cells for each step, and keep steps in ArrayList then move between steps. You ofc have to modify steps wheter user didn't redo and moved etc